# Distinct values of grouped attributes in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have two tables:

```
  Table1   name   object        Table2  name_old   name_corr 
           ------|-----|                ---------|-----------
           John  | A   |                 John    | John
           Ben   | B   |                 Ben     | Ben
           Jon   | B   |                 Jon     | John
           Be n  | B   |                 Be n    | Ben
           Peter | B   |                 Peter   | Peter
           Petera| C   |                 Petera  | Peter
```

In my Example I have three persons, in Table1 there are some typing errors, so Table2 assigns every name to the correct name.

Now I want for every Person (John, Ben, Peter) their distinct objects.

This would be the outcome:

```
John  A
      B
Ben   B
Peter B
      C
```

This was my try, but I get an error:

```
Select b.name_corr, distinct(a.object) from Table1 as a join Table2 as b on (a.name=b.name_old) group by b.name_corr
```

Without the grouping, meaning if I select a specific name via 'where' my query works.

Comment: a bit unclear. Add question and error message to your question please.

Comment: This was supposed to be my question:
"Now I want for every Person (John, Ben, Peter) their distinc objects."
Please compare my posted outcome.

Comment: I added an explanation, what the different name categories mean, if that was perhaps a bit unclear

Answer (score 0):

`distinct` isn't a function.  It is a qualifier on `select`:

```
Select distinct b.name_corr, a.object
from Table1 a join
     Table2 b
     on a.name = b.name_old;
```

Comment: But this way I don't get every distinct object for every name, but only one.

Comment: @Kai . . . I have no idea what your comment is supposed to mean.  This will return every name/object pair once, with no duplicates.  That seems to be the intention of your question.

Comment: It doesn't gibe me the result I described in my question. It won't give me
"John A, B", but only "John A". 
I figured out a solution by myself. 
Thanks anyway!

Comment: This would have both `A` and `B` for `John`.

Answer (score 0):

use `group_concat`:

```
Select b.name_corr, group_concat(distinct a.object) from Table1 as a join Table2 as b on (a.name=b.name_old) group by b.name_corr;
```

Comment: Thanks LFJ, that's a step towards the solution ;)

It works, but is there no way i get every distinct objects in an extra row, not all the objects in a single string?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for my problem. -> Double 'group by'.  So simple..
Thanks for the help anyway.